# Coordinates of new area of a map

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all!

I am using a Pioneer P3AT to apply map building and autonomous navigation using a hokuyo laser with GMapping and Navigation stack. However for the autonomous navigation part, I was success to allow a random selection of unknown cell and move the robot to that cell. After actually applying this to the robot, I realized that the robot seems to be moving in a circle and always stay at the same area.

I thought that if i could obtain the coordinates of the new area being built while mapping, I could direct the robot to move to that area instead..but I don't know if its possible as subscribing the /map topic could publish random points?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66522/coordinates-of-new-area-of-a-map/) by [barrybear](https://answers.ros.org/users/3741/barrybear/) on ROS Answers with karma: 57 on 2013-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not really sure, what you mean, but you can subscribe to the /map topic without any problems. That cannot result in publishing random points in any way.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [barrybear](https://answers.ros.org/users/3741/barrybear/) on 2013-07-03**:
Oh I'm sorry, what I meant was instead of using random coordinates from move_base/local_costmap/unknown_space, I was thinking if its possible to obtain the coordinates of just-discovered-new area in the map and setting it as the move_base_simple/goal

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-07-04**:
In that case, you'd have to track that by recording the change in the map. The easiest would probably be to determine the frontiers and look at which one changes (or just drive to the one in front of the robot)

**Comment by [barrybear](https://answers.ros.org/users/3741/barrybear/) on 2013-07-08**:
Yeah I'm wondering if there is way to do so autonomously.. Cant seem to figure out despite subscribing to the /map and /map_metadata topic

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-07-09**:
If by autonomously, you mean by ROS facilities, then I don't think there is something generic available. You could look into map based exploration packages though. You'd at least get the frontiers.

**Comment by [barrybear](https://answers.ros.org/users/3741/barrybear/) on 2013-07-09**:
Oh okay, I was just thinking if there is a way to extract out the coordinates of the new area of the map being created